# php method chaining, get next method/parameter in the chain

Tags: php, oop, chaining

I am looking for a way to find out what is the next method in PHP OOP chain.
So if I am calling $obj->a()->b() or $obj->a->b
I want that `a()/a` will know that the next chain parameter/method is `b/b()`.

I had played with __get and __call but with no results.

do you have any idea for that?

I am having a lot of libraries that extend the same parent (db models).
currently I am using `$db->modelA->getX()`
I wish to have the option to call `$db->cache->modelA->getX()` and the cache method will call the next methods in the chain, get the result and save it to cache, and next time it will get it from cache immediately.

Comment: What is your use case here?  The concept you are looking for does not exist as those are just a series of methods call being made in order.  Only the caller knows the order of method execution., so you would likely have to do something like `$obj->a('b')->b('c')-c()` to hint to the method the next method that is going to be called.  If order of method calls is that important you might also build a wrapper function which let's you call the function in a desired order like `$obj->wrapper(['a','b','c']);` My guess though is that you just have a bad class design.

Comment: I am having a lot of libraries that extend the parent (db models).
currently I am using `$db->modelA->getX()`
I wish to have the option to call `$db->cache->modelA->getX()` and the cache method will call the next methods in the chain, get the result and save it to cache.

Comment: Then why wouldn't the method chaining be `$db->modelA->getX()->cache()`? Or better yet, you have all your models' get method simply call to a caching class which handling caching behavior (get from cache with fallback DB read and cache write)?

Comment: because then I'll have to run through all my model methods and add `return $this` instead of returning results in order to support chain caching.  
moreover, if the cache method will be called last I would not have the option to check if I am having the result in the cache already

Comment: Yeah.  Again I think you have a bad design here.  Your models are tightly coupled to the DB it seems rather than an abstracted data source, which may be a DB or a cache in front of a DB or whatever other sort of data source you may want to use that would implement an interface your models understand.

Comment: What you should be striving for from the caller's standpoint is really just `$db->modelA-getX()` and the caller knows nothing as to whether the data come directly from DB or from cache, eliminating the need to specifically call for caching behaviors at all.

Comment: I might suggest you put your existing code in a question at codereview.stackexchange.com to get some more detailed feedback on the design itself.

Comment: Mike thanks for your help, my code is a CodeIgniter models, so if there a bad design I'll have to rewrite CI itself. :-)  

there is nothing special to see.  

I am looking for efficient way to cache some of the model methods results instead of rewriting method after method.